# Time complexity (Big O) of nested loops, going through an array of objects, each containing an array property

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science

I'm wondering what the big O notation would be this javascript algorithm:

```
const a = [
  {
    b: [1, 2, 3],
  },
  {
    b: [4, 5, 6],
  },
  {
    b: [7, 8],
  },
  {
    b: [9, 10, 11, 15, 61],
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < a[i].b.length; j++) {
    console.log(a[i].b[j]);
  }
}
```

where the array `a` contains an arbitrary number of objects, each containing an array `b` of arbitrary length.

Intuitively I think the complexity of the algorithm woudln't grow exponentially, so the best guess I came up with is something like `O(n) + O(m)`. I'm wondering if that is correct and if there's a better way to write this as Big O.

Comment: You have two for loops. This makes the time complexity O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

You pass throught each final element once and only once.

So the complexity is just **O(n)**  with **n** the total number of elements.